# What is the probability of a "random" sequence being truly random?

Tags: probability

I'm asking this purely out of curiosity and do not need it for any reason, but it seems like an interesting question (this is my own).

Given:

You need to validate if a sequence X was randomly generated with numbers from 0...n. Do this by returning number from 0 to 100% representing the chance of the sequence being random.

Assuming the following things must be true:

- If n = 0, the result must always be 100%
- If length of X is 0 or 1, the result must always be 100%
- For every length of X for every n, there must be sequence(s) resulting in 100%
- Order of the sequence matters. The chance of sequence [3,5,3,0,1,3,5,3,2,3] with n=5 could for example be 40%, while [3,3,3,3,3,5,0,1,5,2] could be 2%
- We live in a universe where we can only see if 2 elements of the list are equal to eachother, we know of no thing such as elements being higher or smaller than the other. Imagine being the elements 0..n being objects rather than numbers, that can in no way be higher or smaller than another, but can be equal.
- We must not treat special numbers differently from other numbers, for example, we can not treat 10 to be a less random number than 3
- Establishing the latest 2 rules, the chance of [1,2,3] must be equal to [2,1,0] with n=3

Are there algorithms in existence that try to solve this issue or a similar one by approximation?

Comment: Take a look at [randomness tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests).

Comment: I don't see how it could meaningfully ever be $100\%$. I mean, it could, but you can't guarantee that a sequence is random, so I don't know what it would mean.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "the chance of the sequence being random".

Comment: @MattSamuel I thought about this myself but the "number from 0 to 100% representing the chance of the sequence being random" isn't meant to be the exact probability, only something that is related to it and is perhaps stretched out to cover the range 0-100. The likelihood of a sequence being random shouldn't depend on the length of the sequence is the main idea behind me stating it like that

Comment: @joriki I expect an algorithm that will map likelihood of a sequence being generated randomly (by a computer, so truly random numbers) to a number from 0 to 100

Comment: As I already wrote above: You need to define what you mean by "likelihood of a sequence being generated randomly (by a computer)". Apparently you don't mean the probability that a computer would generate this particular sequence while uniformly sampling from all sequences, because in that case this measure would by definition be the same for all sequences.